# Invocar método de um objeto - reflect

Tags: java, string

É possível invocar um método a partir de um conteúdo de uma variável do tipo String?

```
for (Object vlr : dados) {
    String metodo = "getCodigo()";
    contato.setAttribute("codigo", vlr.metodo);
}
```

Comment: Você quer criar um método?!! Não seria invocar um método a partir do nome (Reflection)?

Comment: Exatamente, isso, invocar, irei corrigir a pergunta, poderia me dar informações sobre este reflection, de como eu utilizaria ele para suprir meu problema?

Comment: Muito útil a sua pergunta para mim, não conhecia sobre Reflections, valeu +1

Comment: Sim é possível.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
package java.lang.reflect;
...
//Obtenha a classe pela instancia 
Class clazz = Class.forName( seuObjeto.getClass().getName()  );

//Obtenha o metodo da classe pelo nome
Method metodoDoSeuObjeto = clazz.getMethod( "nomeMetodo" );

//invoque o metodo no seu objeto. "se necessario passe um array de argumentos."
Object retornoDoMetodo = metodoDoSeuObjeto.invoke( seuObjeto, ArrayArgumentos );
```

Answer (score 3):

Segue um exemplo, bem simples de como você brincaria com reflection:
http://rextester.com/ODXCPL39550

E o link da documentação sobre reflextion https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html

---

**UPDATE 2**

Segue o código do exemplo simples:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

class Test
{  
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String className = "TestReflection";
        String[] methodsNames = {"method1", "method2"};

        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
        Object instanceOfClass =  clazz.newInstance();

        for(String s : methodsNames) {
            Class<?>[] paramTypes = null;
            Method m = clazz.getDeclaredMethod(s, paramTypes);
            Object[] varargs = null;
            m.invoke(instanceOfClass, varargs);

            System.out.println(m);
        }
    }
}

class TestReflection {

    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("Method1 chamado");
    }

    public void method2() {
        System.out.println("Method2 chamado");
    }
}
```